# Range of immediates in lui instruction

Tags: mips, instructions, immediate-operand

I'm not sure what is the range bound for the immediate in `lui` instruction.

When I assemble:

```
lui $t0,32768
```

It successfully went without errors.

However,

```
lui $t0,-32768
```

notified that -32768 out of range.

Answer (score 1):

In MIPS the immediate in I-type instructions is always 16-bit long. That means the range will be [0, 65535] if the assembler treats it as unsigned, and [-32768, 32767] for the signed case

However what you can use in the assembly depends on the assembler

For example some assemblers like [shell-storm](http://shell-storm.org/online/Online-Assembler-and-Disassembler/) and [WeMips](https://rivoire.cs.sonoma.edu/cs351/wemips/) accept constants in [-32768, 65535] which is a mix of both 16-bit signed and unsigned, [MIPS Converter](https://www.eg.bucknell.edu/~csci320/mips_web/) only accepts hexadecimal values but [WebMIPSASM](http://www.kurtm.net/mipsasm/index.cgi) accepts even huge values like 9223372036854775807 and truncate the result to 16 bits